# get paid doing smth, get paid for doing smth, get paid to do smth

Tags: grammar

I didn't find anything helpful in the dictionaries.
What is the correct way to use "get paid" when explaining what the person does to earn money? They earn money by doing something like training/coaching people...
You can get paid for coaching kids.
You can get paid coaching kids.
You can get paid to coach kids.

Comment: _For doing_ and _to do_ are both acceptable.

Comment: _Get paid doing something_ is ordinary talk, not for writing; the others are normal. Note that this distribution of grammaticality is guaranteed only for the phrase _get paid_. Every predicate has its own distributional spectrum.

Comment: ... Yes, 'be remunerated' _not_ being 'ordinary talk' so that  'be remunerated doing something' sounds laughable.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear about it. And for writing, which preposition/absence of preposition is correct? Are all of the variants I mentioned acceptable?